# Tensorboard - Filter steps by range

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have multiple models which I want to compare in Tensorflow using Tensorboard, But the problem is that some of them have trained for a long time and some have trained for a limited amount of time and when I try to compare them in Tensorboard, I end up with something like the image below which is really hard to tell apart in the first thousand iterations.

[image: Hard to tell apart Tensorboard plot]

Is there a way to filter out a range for time steps in Tensorboard, for example from 0 to 10000 steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how...

You just have to hold the Left Mouse Button down and select the area on the plot where you want to filter the time steps and voila!

Now the question seems stupid!